# Class Properties... is GET called at every instantiation of the class

Tags: vb.net, class, instantiation

I have a Class "Settings" which is a global available set of properties within my application for each user's settings. It is created by passing a User string into the `New` Sub routine, hugely simplified to:

```
Class Settings
    Property This as string
    Property That as string
    Sub New(User as string)
        ' Get new things from the database and set the properties
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have a property `Websites` which is a collection of `Website` objects, so a more complete model of my Class is

```
Class Settings
    Property This as string
    Property That as string
    Property Websites as List(of Website)
    Sub New(User as string)
        ' Get new things from the database and set the properties
    End Sub
    Class Website
        Property Domain as string
        '.... more properties
    End Class
End Class
```

Getting the websites property takes a bit of time, so for performance, I'd like this property to only be populated when required.

So I write this property as follows:

```
ReadOnly Property Websites() As List(Of Website)
    Get
        If Me.UserKey = "" Then ' Checks if the Parent Class `Settings` exists as an object and has a UserKey
            Throw New Exception("Cannot Fetch Website Objects with no valid Settings Object.")
        End If
        Dim w As List(Of Website) = ' Go to the database and make website objects 
        Return w
    End Get
End Property
```

My question is... will this property be populated at every call of `New Settings(User)`, thus defeating my purpose, or will it remain `null` until I require it and use it in code such as

```
Dim Settings as New Settings(User)
Dim MyWebsiteList as List(of Website) = Settings.Websites
'   Do things with the websites
```

Or... am I going about this all wrong and should just create a function within the settings class and pass the user reference into that...

Comment: *will this property be populated at every call of New Settings(User)*: Yes. You could cache it into a field and return the field if it isn't `Nothing`, instead of going to the DB. I'd suggest looking at the `Lazy` class though, as I believe it will do what you want.

Comment: Oh, Lazy looks interesting. I haven't come across that before.